# What controllers can you use for Minecraft Wii U Edition?

Tags: controllers, minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

I can't figure out what **controllers** I can use in *Minecraft Wii U Edition*.

Comment: Which ones have you tried?  How do they not work?

Comment: I've tried a Wii remote. I've Tried the wii remote with a nunchuck and the both dont work. The internet said to push the + button but, it wont work.

Comment: What doesnt work? Does anything happen?

Answer (score 1):

*Minecraft Wii U Edition* support the Wii U GamePad and the Wii U Pro Controller. ([Source](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/minecraft-wii-u-edition#game-details))